# JSON stringify standalone function for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I know of YUI who has a JSON.stringify utility and also of JSON2 from json.org.

What are other good implementations of JSON.stringify?

It should also work in IE6, IE7 and not depend on a framework.

If it depends on anything this should be easily included all in one file.

*Edit:* I could easily use jquery-json, which was suggested in the comments of the accepted answer. It did what I wanted. (It depends on jquery but that was easily solved)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider ["json-sans-eval"](http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/). I'm using this in [Myna](http://www.mynajs.org) now because it is super fast, ECMAScript 5 conformant, and most importantly, unlike JSON2, it does not use eval() so there is no danger of someone abusing the JSON spec to execute trojan JavaScript code.

Comment: thank you. does it depend on anything external? - karthorwald - aka

Comment: This means it is the answer to the question :-) I will try it out soon. karlthorwald – aka

Comment: That's a parser, not a serializer (stringify).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would recommend you to stay with the [JSON2 library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js), it is really small (*~2.5K minified*), and it uses native implementations if available.

This small standalone library is also compatible with the JSON object described in the [ECMAScript 5 Edition Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

Comment: thank you. so don't you know of other libraries? karlthorwald - aka -

Comment: Yes, I know some other implementations, but they are library-dependent, like [jquery-json](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) or the built-in JSON support added to [PrototypeJS](http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/json).